# Problem with Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addProduct() and Bundled Products

Tags: product, php, module, bundled-product

So I'm trying to add a bundled product to a quote programmatically in a module.  When I add an item to the cart directly from the front-end, it works just fine.  However, when I do it programmatically, I get an error message:

```
Please specify product option(s).
```

The function invocation I'm doing looks a little like this:

```
$productID = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('PKGTEST');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);

$result = $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object([
    'product' => $productID,
    'qty' => 1,
]));
if ($result) {
    throw new Exception($result);
}
```

What is going on here?  How do I add this bundled product to my quote?

---

As an aside, I did notice that some answers to questions about bundled products on this site have `bundle_option` as a part of the `Varien_Object`.  However, the way I have my bundled product set up - the bundle actually has no user-selectable options - means I can skip that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the way I was retrieving the product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
```

The problem with this invocation is that although I am loading the product, the product is ignorant of which storefront it is being loaded for.  The correct invocation is this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeID)->load($productID);
```

Setting the Storefront ID, among other things, fills out a very important data field called `is_salable` in the product.  Without that field, Magento doesn't think that any of the selections for a bundled product are valid because they aren't salable, thus resulting in the error message as described above.